# I do not understand why you have to use the project.build.resources for maven resources

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-resources-plugin

From [Maven resources plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/plugin-info.html)

> Copy resources for the main source code to the main output directory. Always uses the project.build.resources element to specify the resources to copy.

Why? It just seems confusing to have these two ways of doing the same thing and then be told, make sure you do it this one way. Can somebody explain?

Comment: This says that the plugin uses this element from the pom.xml file. This means also that you can change the [information in your pom file](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the question. You mention using project.build.resources, but say there are two ways to do it. What's the other way you are talking about?